# there is a partition on my linux system with the partition type W95 FAT32 , what is it?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

after running a number of smart scans, i have noticed that a lot of the bad sectors/problems on my disk come from this partition, even though it only has 1 mb [538 mb size, 537 mb free], i was wondering if it's safe to write zeros to.

Comment: No, it's definitely not safe to write zeroes to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your Master Boot Record - the partition from which your system boots.

This is what it looks like on my system.

[image]

Might be best to leave that partition well alone unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: That is not the MBR. It is the UEFI partition."The MBR consists of 512 or more bytes located in the first sector of the drive."-wikipedia You're right about not messing with it though.